# I am getting for an erroc ZeroDivisionErrror: integer division or modulo by zero. What is wrong with my code

Tags: python

```
for i,j in enumerate(output.readlines()):
    if i%len(tag) == 0:
         [1]
         [2]
         etc
         if i%len(tag) == len(tag) - 1:
            outputfile.write(<"something">)
```

There is more code, but I have just been having a problem with the `ZeroDivisionError` since I edited the first 2 and last 2 lines of this code. I don't know why this error has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check and make sure that len(tag) is not 0 before you ever try to mod(**%**) another value by it. A mod(**%**) is basically a divide operation, so **if len(tag) equals 0, you will get the ZeroDivisionError**.

Consider the following code which will escape the for loop if len(tag) equals 0:

```
for i,j in enumerate(output.readlines()):
    if len(tag) == 0:
        continue
    elif i % len(tag) == 0:
        #Rest of your code here.. 
        if i % len(tag) == len(tag) - 1:
            outputfile.write("something")
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily just use `if`s like this to avoid the problem. There is probably some reason `len(tag)` is `0` when it shouldn't be. Hard to say without seeing more code though.

Comment: The program that I am writing after the line if i%len(tag) ==0:  we specify the tags with the associated string/index of the line, than write to that new file adding more string to the tag, than the if i % len(tag) - 1: occurs than the outputfile.write

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in this part of the code, then `len(tag)` equals `0` at some point. (`x%0` is not defined, just like `x/0`.)

Put `print tag` before the if statements and see where the problem is.

I can't get more specific without seeing more code (where `tag` is defined/modified, etc.).